# Unable to save image within a sub folder in a folder

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

` [TearDown]
        public void Screenshot()
        {

```
        if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome != ResultState.Success)
        {
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style.border='3px solid red'", element);
            Screenshot image = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
            string testMethodName = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name;
            image.SaveAsFile("C:/temp/Images" + testMethodName + ".png", ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
        }
```

`So I am trying to save my Screenshot Image (Screenshot on fail test case) into a sub-folder in a folder using Selenium Webdriver Nunit C#. But I am unable to save it into the sub-folder. The image will be saved but it will only be saved in the Folder and not in the sub-folder.

So,I am trying to save the image into the a subfolder in "Temp" named as "Images", but when the screenshot saved, it was named with the name "Images" + Test Method that had failed (For this case , the test method is called "TestFail") as well and the image stored in the Folder "Temp". The image is named as "ImageTestFail.png"  stored in Temp folder. I wanted to save the "TestFail.png" under the sub-folder Images.[enter To View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVOV1.png)

Comment: You are missing `/` after `images`, `"C:/temp/Images/" + testMethodName + ".png"`

Comment: Lmfao, thanks, you solved ma problem. I didnt realise i need to put a "/" at the back . Thanks mate